# Best way to output prediction result for a test set from a model with 1 output (binary classification)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

This seems simple, but I'm looking for the best way to output the prediction results for a model with 1 output (binary classification model). My labels are 0 and 1 in this example. Now I can just say if model output > 0.5 label is 1. But I'm sort of guessing this is correct. I am hence wondering if there is a better approach, like

```
prediction = np.argmax(y_hat.detach().numpy, axis=0) for multiple classes.
```

Currently I'm doing this to test:

```
test = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]]

for trial in test: 
  Xtest = torch.Tensor(trial)
  y_hat = logreg_clf(Xtest)

  if y_hat > 0.5:
    prediction = 1
  else: 
    prediction = 0
  # prediction = np.argmax(y_hat.detach().numpy, axis=0)
  print("{0} xor {1} = {2}".format(int(Xtest[0]), int(Xtest[1]), prediction))
```

Was also wondering if there is a function to automatically get the accuracy or confusion matrix for test set 'test'.

FYI my model:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
  # input_size: Dimensionality of input feature vector.
  # num_classes: The number of classes in the classification problem.
  def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
    # Always call the superclass (nn.Module) constructor first!
    super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
    # Set up the linear transform
    self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
    # I do not yet include the sigmoid activation after the linear 
    # layer because our loss function will include this as you will see later

  # Forward's sole argument is the input.
  # input is of shape (batch_size, input_size)
  def forward(self, x):
    # Apply the linear transform.
    # out is of shape (batch_size, num_classes). 
    out = self.linear(x)
    out = F.sigmoid(out)
    # Softmax the out tensor to get a log-probability distribution
    # over classes for each example.
    return out

# Binary classifiation
num_outputs = 1
num_input_features = 2

# Create the logistic regression model
logreg_clf = LogisticRegression(num_input_features, num_outputs)

print(logreg_clf)

import torch 
lr_rate = 0.001  # alpha

# training set of input X and labels Y
X = torch.Tensor([[0,0],[0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
Y = torch.Tensor([0,1,1,0]).view(-1,1) #view is similar to numpy.reshape() here it makes it into a column

# Run the forward pass of the logistic regression model
sample_output = logreg_clf(X) #completely random at the moment
print(X)

loss_function = nn.BCELoss() 
# SGD: stochastic gradient descent is used to train/fit the model
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(logreg_clf.parameters(), lr=lr_rate)


import numpy as np 
# from torch.autograd import Variable

#training loop:

epochs = 2001 #how many times we go through the training set
steps = X.size(0) #steps = 4; we have 4 training examples (I know, tiny training set :)

for i in range(epochs):
    for j in range(steps):
        # randomly sample from the training set:
        data_point = np.random.randint(X.size(0))
        # store the retrieved datapoint into 2 separate variables of the right shape
        x_var = torch.Tensor(X[data_point]).unsqueeze(0)
        y_var = torch.Tensor(Y[data_point])

        optimizer.zero_grad() # empty (zero) the gradient buffers
        y_hat = logreg_clf(x_var) #get the output from the model
        print(y_hat)
        print(y_var)
        loss = loss_function(y_hat, y_var) #calculate the loss
        loss.backward() #backprop
        optimizer.step() #does the update

    if i % 500 == 0:
        print ("Epoch: {0}, Loss: {1}, ".format(i, loss.data.numpy()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_data = torch.Tensor(test)
raw_preds = logreg_clf(test_data)
preds = (raw_preds > 0.5).long()
```

To get the predictions for all test data at once, we first convert the test data to a tensor, then we can make a forward pass with that tensor. 
The raw predictions are something like `tensor([[0.4795], [0.4749], [0.4960], [0.5006]]`. 
Then we apply the "risk neutral strategy" i.e. 0.5 as the threshold to get the results (which will be of type `torch.bool` so we convert it to `long`).

Equivalently in one line:

```
preds = (logreg_clf(torch.Tensor(test)) > 0.5).long()
```

So  the predictions are:

```
tensor([[0], [0], [0], [1]])
```

> wondering if there is a function to automatically get the accuracy or confusion matrix

You can use respective functions from [`sklearn.metrics`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics):

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

# the ground truth for the given test data
truth = torch.Tensor([0, 1, 0, 1]).view(-1, 1) 

conf_mat = confusion_matrix(truth, preds)
acc = accuracy_score(truth, preds)
```

which gives the confusion matrix as

```
array([[2, 0],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

and the accuracy as

```
0.75
```

So you have one false negative i.e. the second sample in the test data.